# Unable to disable root logins via phpmyadmin Debian 8

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to prevent root logins via phpmyadmin but I can't get it to work.

/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = false;
```

I've already disabled remote root logins for MySQL (MariaDB) but since phpmyadmin act as local that shouldn't matter.

How can I disable root logins via phpmyadmin on Debian 8 ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work by changing **/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php** instead of **/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php**.

After:

```
if (!empty($dbname)) {
```

I added:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = false;
```